# How to set parameters in managed bean from JavaScript in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have two autocomplete fields as below. I swap the autocomplete values using a command button. I need to persist the swapped values.

```html
    <p:column colspan="2" rendered="#{empty contactController.selectedContact}">
         <p:autoComplete id="contactName1" value="#{newContactRs.contact}"
                         completeMethod="#{contactRelationshipController.completeContacts}"
                         var="contact" itemLabel="#{contact.fullName}"
                         itemValue="#{contact}" converter="#{contactConverter}"
                         forceSelection="true" size="35" scrollHeight="200"
                         panelStyle="width:10px;">
              <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="contactName1" />
          </p:autoComplete>
          <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w" id="flipButton" 
                           styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon" oncomplete="swapInput()"              update="addNewContactRelationshipPanel" immediate="true"/>
          <smith:contactSelector value="#{newContactRs.contact}" update=":addContactRelationshipForm:addNewContactRelationshipPanel" triggerId="existingContactSelector1" resultList="#{contactRelationshipController.selectAllContact1}"/>
   </p:column>

   <p:column colspan="2">
        <p:autoComplete id="contactName2" value="#{newContactRs.relatedContact}"
                        completeMethod="#{contactRelationshipController.completeContacts}"
                        var="contact" itemLabel="#{contact.fullName}"
                        itemValue="#{contact}" converter="#{contactConverter}"
                        forceSelection="true" size="35" scrollHeight="200"
                        panelStyle="width:10px;">
             <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="contactName2" />
         </p:autoComplete>
    <smith:contactSelector value="#{newContactRs.relatedContact}" update=":addContactRelationshipForm:addNewContactRelationshipPanel" triggerId="existingContactSelector2" resultList="#{contactRelationshipController.selectAllContact2}"/>
    </p:column>
```

On clicking the commandbutton with id "flipButton" following javascript is called and it swaps the values of the autocomplete fields

```
function swapInput()
{
    var input_a =document.getElementById('addContactRelationshipForm:contactName1_input').value; 
    var input_b =document.getElementById('addContactRelationshipForm:contactName2_input').value;

    document.getElementById('addContactRelationshipForm:contactName1_input').value = input_b;
    document.getElementById('addContactRelationshipForm:contactName2_input').value = input_a;
}
```

After swapping the values am trying to persist the swapped values but original values are persisting instead of swapped values. I have to set the swapped values in the backing bean but am not sure how to do it, using javascript or primefaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `commandButton` as

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w" 
                 id="flipButton" 
                 styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon" 
                 oncomplete="swapInput()" 
                 update="addNewContactRelationshipPanel" 
                 immediate="true" 
                 process="@this" 
                 actionListener="#{contactRelationshipController.setSwapInputFlag()}"/>
```

and then check for the `swapInputFlag` while persisting the autocomplete fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Preimefaces p:remoteCommand to execute managed bean methods.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml